# Passing a resource to entity constructor

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have two classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`order`")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Trader buyer;

    @ManyToOne
    public Trader seller;

    @ManyToOne
    public PriceTable priceTable;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    public Double price;
    public Integer quantity;

    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String code;

    @ManyToOne
    public Item item;

    @ManyToMany
    public Set<Option> options;

    @JsonCreator(mode=JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public OrderItem(
            @JsonProperty("quantity") Integer quantity,
            @JsonProperty("price") Double price,
            @JsonProperty("item") Item item

            ){
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.item = item;
        this.name = item.name;

    }

}
```

`OrderItem` is managed by `OrderRepository` and does not have it's own repository. I post the following JSON as a new order:

```
{ 
   "seller":"http://localhost:8080/ErPApI/traders/1",
   "buyer":"http://localhost:8080/ErPApI/traders/2",
   "priceTable":"http://localhost:8080/ErPApI/priceTables/1",
   "items":[  
      {  
         "quantity":"5",
         "price":"13",
         "item":"http://localhost:8080/ErPApI/items/1"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I get

> "Can not construct instance of erp.model.oms.item.Item: no
>   String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String
>   value ('http://localhost:8080/ErPApI/items/1')\n at [Source:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@676c47fe; line: 9,
>   column: 14] (through reference chain:
>   erp.model.oms.order.Order[\"items\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->erp.model.oms.order.OrderItem[\"item\"])"

as a response. How can I tell spring that "http://localhost:8080/ErPApI/items/1" is a resource link and not a string?